# how to use "npx webpack-cli init"

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

```
mkdir demo & cd demo
npm init -y
npm i --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
npm i webpack-cli @webpack-cli/init
npx webpack-cli init
```

but when run

```
npx webpack-cli init
```

i get the error

```
init isn't a valid name.

It should be prefixed with 'webpack-scaffold', but have different suffix.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `@webpack-cli/init@0.2.2`.
There are some problems with `0.3` https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1127
Also in `webpack-cli@beta` (v4), they renamed `init` to `create`.

Answer (score 1):

use `npx webpack-cli create` instead `npx webpack-cli init`

Comment: What's the difference?